# Visual Studio - lines being highlighted in yellow while debugging

Tags: c#, visual-studio

[image]

I would like to know how to step into the highlighted yellow area to find out the response of the variable listAgents. When i debug it is just skipping the yellow area and jumping to the next line. Any suggestions?

Comment: Click to the left of 256 to put a breakpoint on that line.

Comment: You'll have to add the breakpoint and cause the event to be fired. Your delegate is an event handler, called when the `AgentConnectionUp` event fires.  Depending on _all_ of your code, you may be adding this event handler _after_ the event fires. If the event only fires once (or not at all), you may never hit your breakpoint.

Comment: @mjwills even when I add a breakpoint the debugger is not stepping into the highlighted area

Comment: @ps2goat I think you are right. how can I add the  event handler after the event fires?

Comment: You already are, the event may just not be firing.  You need to add the event handler _before_ the event fires in order to catch it.  I don't know how to do that without seeing most of your code, the dependencies, etc.

Comment: The only thing that line is doing, is to create an eventhandler. This code will only get executed when that event happens

Comment: @R.Kaushek Think of `AgentConnectionUp` like a `Click` event. The code in a `Click` event handler won't execute **unless someone clicks**. Similarly, if you aren't hitting a breakpoint inside the delegate it is almost certainly since `AgentConnectionUp` is not firing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like you are trying to debug an anonymous function. Pressing F10 or F11 will simply jump over the statement as VS does not know when this delegate will be executed.
To debug anonymous methods put a break point inside the function body and invoke the delegate.

Comment: thanks for your reply. what do you mean by an anonymous function?

Comment: This MS documentation may help regarding anonymous methods https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/anonymous-methods

Answer (score 1):

To jump to the next line use either `F10` or `F11`.

`F10` jumps over them,
`F11` goes into the methods

EDIT:
in your case: set the breakpoint in the executing block (shortcut for setting a breakpoint: `F9`)

Comment: That didn't work. unable to step into that area using F10 and F11 keys

Comment: yes i tried. but it is not giving the response. anyways thanks for your reply mate.